# PyCharm SSH interpreter - env: /Program Files/Python 3.5/python.exe: No such file or directory

Tags: python, ssh, pycharm, windows-server-2012

I am using Windows 10, and I am SSHing onto a Windows Server 2012 VM. This VM has OpenSSH installed, and I can SSH onto it using Putty and run python.

On PyCharm 2018, I am attempting to add a SSH interpreter. I go to project interpreter, connect to the SSH Server, and then it asks me to specify the python interpreter. I open the browse button, and I find the python interpreter and click on it. The interpreter text box is then filled with the following text:

`/Program Files/Python 3.5/python.exe`

Then I hit "finish". I get a "Getting remote interpreter" loading box for some time, then I get the following as command output:

```
env: /Program Files/Python 3.5/python.exe: No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 127
```

When I try a file that actually doesn't exist in that folder, it doesn't load it and immediately gives me an error. So clearly pycharm knows that there is a python environment there...

Here's an interesting thing: I can literally load *a text file in the same directory as python.exe* and pycharm will interpret it as an interpreter. But not the actual interpreter.

What can I do?